# getting specific xml data using c#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

i have an xml file:

```
<Address>
  <Data2>
    <Person>
      <EMPL_NUM>>100</EMPL_NUM>
      <NAME>Carl</NAME>
      <ID_NUM>1</ID_NUM>
      <IsRequired>0</IsRequired>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <EMPL_NUM>200</EMPL_NUM>
      <NAME>Mark</NAME>
      <ID_NUM>2</ID_NUM>
      <IsRequired>0</IsRequired>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <EMPL_NUM>300</EMPL_NUM>
      <NAME>Tanner</NAME>
      <ID_NUM>3</ID_NUM>
      <IsRequired>0</IsRequired>
    </Person>
 </Data2>
</Address>
```

I have a textbox and a button. When I type "1" and press the button my problem is how can i display the xml data to a datagridview where the value of the textbox would only show the data that has ID_num = textbox.text

expected output to datagrid:

```
if txtbox1.text = 1:

 EMPL_NUM  |  Name  |  ID_NUM  |  IsRequired                  
   100     |  Carl  |    1     |      0

if txtbox1.text = 3:

 EMPL_NUM  |  Name  |  ID_NUM  |  IsRequired                  
   300     | Tanner |    3     |      0
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read `ID_NUM = 1` from your XML file?

Comment: yes sir. if textbox1.text =1 then this should display the  empl_num, name, id_num and isrequired that has an id_num equal to the value of the the textbox1.text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // read your xml from somewhere
        var xml = File.ReadAllText("Address.xml");
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        // get the element by id
        var element = GetElementById(xmldoc, 1);

        // deserialize element
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        var person = (Person)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(element.CreateReader());

        // continue to work with person
    }

    private static XElement GetElementById(XDocument xmldoc, string id)
    {
        // Elements according to your XML file
        var element = xmldoc.Element("Address")
            .Elements("Data2")
            .Elements("Person")
            .Single(x => x.Element("ID_NUM").Value == id);
        return element;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Used for deserialization
/// </summary>
public class Person
{
    public int EMPL_NUM { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int ID_NUM { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, i tried this code but got this error " Sequence contains no matching element"

Comment: this code works against your XML. The only thing i changed in your XML ist line 4: `<EMPL_NUM>>100</EMPL_NUM>` to `<EMPL_NUM>100</EMPL_NUM>`